# Meteor-Autoform doesn't render properly

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have issue with Meteor Autoforms, the form doesn't render properly.

My code is here:

```
<template name="insertBookForm">
{{> quickForm id="fields1" collection="FieldsExamples" schema=Schemas.FieldsExamples }}
</template>

FieldsExamples = new Mongo.Collection("fieldsExamples");

var Schemas = {};

Schemas.FieldsExamples = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  address: {
    type: Object
  },
  'address.street': {
    type: String
  },
  'address.street2': {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  'address.city': {
    type: String
  },
  'address.state': {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ["AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","FL","GA","HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD","MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","OH","OK","OR","PA","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","WA","WV","WI","WY"],
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        firstOption: "(Select a State)"
      }
    }
  },
  'address.postalCode': {
    type: String,
    label: "ZIP"
  },
  contacts: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
  },
  'contacts.$': {
    type: Object
  },
  'contacts.$.name': {
    type: String
  },
  'contacts.$.phone': {
    type: String
  }
});
```

This is just simple example I got off from site http://autoform.meteor.com/qfdetails

What I get is this:

[image: [img]http://i.imgur.com/a5WbMRN.png?1[/img]]
but it should be normal from to enter data into collection

Answer (score 1):

Did you attach your schema to your collection?

```
FieldsExamples.attachSchema(Schemas.FieldsExamples);
```